# American option pricing using path integrals

Tags: option-pricing, american-options

I am writing a brute force code in python that implements the path integral formalism for the American put option, the goal being to obtain its price at given a price $S_0$ of the underlying asset.
Let $r$, $\sigma$, and $\mu$ are positive constants. To solve it, I numerically evaluate this integral (using numpy.trapz):

$$V(t_{i-1}, x_{i-1})= e^{-r(t_{i}-t_{i-1})}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx_{i} \cdot G(x_{i}, t_{i}|x_{i-1}, t_{i-1})V(t_i, x_{i}),$$

where $G$ is a *propagator* defined by:
$$G(x_{i}, t_{i}|x_{i-1},t_{i-1}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^{2}(t_{i}-t_{i-1})}}exp\Biggl(-\frac{[(x_{i}-x_{i-1})-\mu \cdot(t_{i}-t_{i-1})]^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}(t_{i}-t_{i-1})}\Biggr).$$

where $t \in (0, T ) $ and $x =\ln{S}$ $\in (-\infty, +\infty )$, where $S$ is the underlying asset price. The value of the option $V(t_N = T, x_T)$ is propagated back to every price point at time $t_{N-1}$ finding the function $V(t_{N-1}, x_{N-1})$ for all $x$ at that time. Then the exercise condition is checked (the payoff and the continuation value are compared and the greater was taken) and the result is used to find $V(t_{N-2}, x_{N-2})$. This process is repeated until we find $V(t_{0}, x_{0})$.

Practically, I discretize the $t$ and $x$ domains into $N_t$ time steps and $N_x$ price steps, creating a uniform grid in the $(t, x)$ plane, such that each point on the grid can be labeled by two indices $x_{i, j}$, where the $i$ index gives the time position, and the $j$ index gives the position in the $x$ direction. I then performed a nested loop to loop over the $i$ and $j$ indices and obtained $V(t_{0}, x_{0, j})$.

I compared the results to the binomial model and noticed that if the number of price steps $N_x$ is much larger than the number of time steps $N_t$, then the code converges very close to the value predicted by the binomial model. However, I do not understand why as I increase the number of time steps $N_t$, the agreement with the binomial model starts to deviate from the binomial model (this effect is not large, but it is significant enough to ruin the model), and if we increase $N_t$ sufficiently, the result diverges completely, giving absurdly large values for the option price.

After playing with the values $N_t$ and $N_x$ for a bit, I think I noticed that if I want to maintain convergence, then if I increase $N_t$ by a factor $p$, I have to increase $N_x$ by a factor of about $p^2$, although I have no rigorous reason to think this other than the fact that seems to work. How do I explain this? Is there some convergence condition that I am not aware of, or is there some way to get around this problem?

Comment: Intuitively, for a diffusion process, $dx^2$ is of the same  scale as $dt$.  Keeping these in the same ratio would suggest the behavior you observe.

Comment: Would there be a way to find some sort of convergence condition? Like for example, in the explicit finite difference method, we have to ensure that the condition $\sigma^2 S^2\frac{dt}{dS^2} \leq 1$ is satisfied.